How to handle "multiple" conditional probability like P(A|B|C)?
We know that P(A|B)=P(A,B)/P(B) but what if we want to find the analog for this "multiple" conditioning P(A|B|C)?

P(A|B|C) does not have a meaning. If you know the value of a RV or event, it's on the RHS. If you don't know it, it's on the LHS. So, if you know both B and C, it is P(A|B,C)

i'm asking this question because in my professor's slide is written basically a relation like this: P(A| (B|C) )=P(A|B,C)/P(A|C) and I can't explain why. If what you're saying is always true maybe there's an error

I'm not able to make sense of the relation, letting alone what it actually means. If $C$ is an always true event, something given $C$, i.e. $X|C$ would not affect $X$ in anyway. So, removing C from the equation all together yields $$P(A|B)=P(A|B)/P(A)$$ This does not make sense to me.

Also, I'm not sure what makes $P(A|B,C)/P(A|C)$ a probability. If that is guaranteed to be a probability, so is $P(A|B)/P(A)$ without loss of generality. But, this is simply not true. If $B=A$, the expression is $1/P(A)$ which is certainly not a probability in general. So, I think there are several typos in the slides.
